# Web reference created dynamically

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin

I'm developing android app on Xamarin Android in c#.
 Is there any way to change dynamically URL of SOAP web service? I want to store url in some kind of config file but I have no idea how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct me, if i'm wrong

but the second constructor of an xamarin - soap webservice class has a property for URL.

Here's an example of my webservice:

```
public partial class Service : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol 
    {                    
                public Service() 
                {
                    this.Url = "http://xxx/service.asmx";
                }

                public Service(string url) 
                {
                    this.Url = url;
                }
    }
```

you've added the webreference in xamarin and then use your webservice - instance.

Just call the second constructor and give them an other url as source.

Answer (score 1):

You could manually create your required connection using Channelfactory that changes as it needs to. You'll need the proper connections in the web.config file.

Here's a way you could set it up.

In your **web.config**.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Identity" value="machineidentity" />
    <add key="Binding" value="WSHttpBinding_IService" />
    <add key="Endpoint" value="http://Devservice/Service.svc" />
    <add key="Identity2" value="localmachine" />
    <add key="Binding2" value="WSHttpBinding_IService" />
    <add key="Endpoint2" value="http://Devservice/Service.svc" />
    <add key="devIdentity" value="localmachine" />
    <add key="devBinding" value="WSHttpBinding_IService" />
    <add key="devEndpoint" value="http://Devservice/Service.svc" />
  </appSettings>
```

**C#** code

a configuration class to hold values from the web.config

```
public static Dictionary<int, Connections> EndpointConnections = new Dictionary<int, Connections>
    {
        {1, new Connections(){Identity = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Identity"],Binding = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Binding"], Endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Endpoint"]}},
        {2, new Connections(){Identity = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Identity2"],Binding = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Binding2"], Endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Endpoint2"]}},
        {3, new Connections(){Identity = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["devIdentity"],Binding = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["devBinding"], Endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["devEndpoint"]}},
   };
```

Now a static class for creating the endpoint

```
private ChannelFactory<IService> SetChannelFactory(int configInput)
            {
                var identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(Configuration.EndpointConnections[configInput].Identity);
                var myBinding = new WSHttpBinding(Configuration.EndpointConnections[configInput].Binding);
                var myuri = new Uri(Configuration.EndpointConnections[configInput].Endpoint);
                var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(myuri, identity);

                return new ChannelFactory<IService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
            }
```

Now calling and using the endpoint

```
public async Task<Result> SomeAction(int selection)
{
        IService client = null;
        Result result = null;
        Response response = null;

        using (var myChannelFactory = SetChannelFactory(selection))
        {
             try
             {
                  client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                  response = await client.TheServiceFunction().ConfigureAwait(false);
                  ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
             }
             catch
             {
                  if (client != null)
                  {
                       ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
                       return new result ( failure = true);
                  }
             }
        }
        if (response != null)
        {
                 //Whatever you want to do with the response here
                 return new result ( failure = false);
        }
}
```